# Can anyone help with calculating the dimension of a quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

The question I am attempting is part b) of the following:

(a) Show that the $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $d_{x y}: \mathbb{R}[x, y] /\left(x^{2}, y^{2}\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $d_{x y}\left(f+\left(x^{2}, y^{2}\right)\right):=$ $\frac{d^{2} f}{d x d y}(0,0)$ is well defined.

(b) Compute the dimension over $\mathbb{R}$ of the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x, y] /\left(x^{2}, y^{2}\right) .$ (Hint: find a spanning set to provide an upper bound. For the lower bound it is not enough to consider the evaluation map for the point $(0,0)$. In addition to the evaluation map, consider maps which take a given element to a partial derivative).
$[4]$

For the first I went about showing that two values that repeat the same element in the quotient map to the same element under $d_{xy}$

However for b) I really don’t know where to start with the evaluation map regarding partial derivatives.

I was half thinking of showing an isomorphism to $\Bbb R^4$ and showing the dimension this way?

I’m new to earning ideals and definitely feel like I’ve been thrown in the deep end.

If anyone could give me any help or just point me in the direction of what to show, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In (b) the situation is just that $V = \mathbb{R}[x, y]/(x^2, y^2)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-module, i.e. real vector space, so has some dimension (over $\mathbb{R}$). We know from linear algebra that the dimension of a vector space is less than or equal to the cardinality of any spanning set, and that's why the first hint is to produce a spanning set.

If you can show that the $\mathbb{R}$-span of the set $S = \{1, x, y, xy\}$ is all of $\mathbb{R}[x, y]/(x^2, y^2)$ (try this!), then you know that $\dim V \leq 4$.

Now we just need to show that the set $S$ is actually a basis for $V$ (i.e. its elements are linearly independent). Let's just do this from first principles: suppose that $a \cdot 1 + b \cdot x + c \cdot y + d \cdot xy = 0$ for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. (We want to show that $a = b = c = d = 0$.)

As suggested in the hint, recall that there is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism $\operatorname{ev}_{(0,0)} : \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2) \to \mathbb{R}$ (in particular an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map) which sends $x$ and $y$ both to zero, called evaluation at $0$. Applying $\operatorname{ev}_{(0,0)}$ to our relation above we get
$$
a = a + 0 + 0 + 0 = \operatorname{ev}_{(0,0)}(a \cdot 1 + b \cdot x + c \cdot y + d \cdot x y)
= \operatorname{ev}_{(0,0)}(0) = 0.
$$
This shows that $a = 0$. The hint now says to consider the maps $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2) \to \mathbb{R}$ caled $d_x$ and $d_y$, which take partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively, and then evaluate at $(0, 0)$ in each case. This is just a fancy way of saying that $d_x$ is the map which sends $1 \mapsto 0$, $x \mapsto 1$, $y \mapsto 0$, and $x y \mapsto 0$. Similarly $d_y$ is the map which sends $1 \mapsto 0$, $x \mapsto 0$, $y \mapsto 1$, and $x y \mapsto 0$. (*One issue here is that if you haven't checked that these definitions of $d_x$ and $d_y$ actually give well-defined $\mathbb{R}$-module homomorphisms, then you need to check this at this point, but this is not a big deal.*)

Ok, but assuming that you've done this we can now just do the same thing: applying $d_x$ and $d_y$ to our relation $b \cdot x + c \cdot y = 0$ we get
$$
b = d_x(b \cdot x + c \cdot y + d \cdot xy) = 0
\quad \text{and} \quad
c = d_y(b \cdot x + c \cdot y + d \cdot xy) = 0,
$$
from which we conclude that $b = c = 0$ as well. Finally, using the map $d_{x y}$ from part (a) we see that $d = 0$ in exactly the same way. This now shows that the elements of the $\mathbb{R}$-spanning set $S$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent, and thus completes the proof.

Comment: @AdelaideDokras You're not mistaken.  You need to include $xy$ for $S$ to be a spanning set as an $\Bbb R$-linear vector space.

Comment: Surely the upper bound is 4 since the basis is (1,x,y,xy) not just (1,x,y). Also how come you didn’t need to consider the mixed partial?

Comment: @AdelaideDokras Sorry, oops!